# How to Override Identity Management module for Multi-Tenancy

Tags: abp

I was wondering how to Override the [Identity Management Module](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/tree/dev/modules/identity) to Work with Multi-tenant Web-Apps in [Abp Framework](https://github.com/abpframework/abp) . I want to Make my newly registered Users to become the admin of their own tenant and be able to Manage (Crud + Permission / Role Management ) their Subset users? For now I've created a custom UI to manage them, but I'm curios if it's possible to configure the Identity Management Module to do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok looks like I just need to create an "Admin" role and make it my default role for each tennet

https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/10995

Comment: What do you think about it now? We have no access to AccountAppService on version 7.0. I created a new module, but it throws me no permissions because I need the admin role.